# Google Adwords Api error invalid content was found

Tags: node.js, soap, google-ads-api

Im using a nodejs package for the Google adwords Api, i am getting the following error:

```
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a
: Invalid content was found starting with element \'serviceSelector\'. One of \'{"https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201609":selector}\' is expected. </faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:B
ody></soap:Envelope>' }
```

I am trying to get keywords ideas. My code looks like this:

```
var TargetingIdeaService = user.getService('TargetingIdeaService', 'v201609')

//create selector 
var selector = {
    SearchParameter:{[RelatedToQuerySearchParameter:'Test']},
    IdeaType:'KEYWORDS',
    requestType:'IDEAS',
    requestedAttributeTypes: ['TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES'],
    paging: {startIndex: 0, numberResults: AdwordsConstants.RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE}
}

TargetingIdeaService.get({serviceSelector: selector}, function (error, result) {
    console.log(error, result);
})
```

Any ideas on why this is not working, thanks in advance.

Using this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201609/TargetingIdeaService

Answer (score 0):

The required parameter for the `get` call ist `selector`, not `serviceSelector`.

Also, I've noticed that you linked to an old version of the API documentation—be aware that `v201609` is deprecated and will be sunset on 2 October 2017. Here's the [up-to-date documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService#get).